Esri shapefile converter to PDF/picture format
is there any converter that can convert Esri shapefiles into PDF or some image format such as JPEG or PNG?
My organization has dbf, prj, sbn, sbx, shp and shx files in database, and now I need to convert them to an archive form (preferably to PDF). Another complication is that the conversion process must be executable via the command line.

Shapefile are GIS data meaning that they have geometry and attribute what do you want to convert ?  what should the output look like ? Why choosing PDF as archive format (I don't think PDF is a "good" format for GIS data)

I think we need more information, so please edit your question. What do you mean by dbf, sbn, ... in a database? Does the database contain the actual files? What are the requirements for this 'archive'? Can't you just archive the files? Or make a backup of your database?

See https://spatial-dev.guru/2021/12/04/ogr2ogr-a-simple-command-line-tool-to-transform-your-gis-data/

There are an infinite number of ways to convert vector data to raster, and none of them would make a better "archive" than shapefile (which is an archaic format, no longer capable of storing all the data regularly available in GIS).

Basic option with no cartography is GDAL commandline tool ogr2ogr - ogr2ogr output,pdf input.shp.
